# Fetch "current datetime" from Postgres Database instead of PDI server/client time using Table Input step

Tags: postgresql, pg, pdi

Fetch "current datetime" from Postgres Database instead of PDI server/client  time using Table Input step.

When I use "Table Input" step to get the Postgres Timestamp, I am getting PDI server/client time.

How to get Postgres DB timestamp instead PDI Server/Client time.

```
     , TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')  p_to_date1 
     , TO_CHAR(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')  p_to_date2
     , TO_CHAR(CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP), 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') p_to_date3
```

p_to_date1  --> 2023/02/03 11:34:54

p_to_date2 --> 2023/02/03 11:34:54

p_to_date3  --> 2023/02/03 11:34:54

Comment: Please define PDI.

Comment: is Duser.timezone set in spoon.bat/spoon.sh? This might cause it. Some reading on it: [link](https://community.hitachivantara.com/communities/community-home/digestviewer/view-question?ContributedContentKey=24b0321d-1937-46c9-8abb-199ba50ce7fe&CommunityKey=e0eaa1d8-5ecc-4721-a6a7-75d4e890ee0d)